# Sending files between computers remotely

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, sftp, updates

How can I send and receive files remotely, and also push updates via python? We have a bunch of devices out in the market and they are all Windows ten based. How could we go about sending files to those machines and receive files from those machines? We would like to use python for this task. Any tutorials or articles could be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this script a while ago to send files to my remote SFTP server from my local laptop. The machines has each other's public keys:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko


fpaths = ['list/of', 'file/paths']

with pysftp.Connection(server, username='loginID') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('target/directory'):
        for fpath in fpaths:
            print("Sending:", fpath)

            if not os.path.isdir(fpath):
                sftp.put(fpath)
                print("Permissioning", fpath)
                sftp.chmod(os.path.basename(fpath), 755)

            else:
                dirname = os.path.basename(fpath)
                if not sftp.isdir(dirname):
                    sftp.mkdir(dirname)
                    print("Permissioning", dirname)
                    sftp.chmod(os.path.basename(dirname), 755)

                sftp.put_r(fpath, dirname)

                sftp.walktree(dirname,
                              dcallback=lambda dname:print("Permissioning", dname) or sftp.chmod(dname, 755),
                              fcallback=lambda fname:print("Permissioning", fname) or sftp.chmod(fname, 755),
                              ucallback=lambda x:x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) package for python ftp connection. [Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/how-to-use-ftp-in-python) is the small tutorial for that.

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP("www.python.org")
ftp.login("anonymous", "ftplib-example-1")

data = []

ftp.dir(data.append)

ftp.quit()

for line in data:
    print "-", line
```

Executing above code example:

```
$ python ftplib-example-1.py
- total 34
- drwxrwxr-x  11 root     4127         512 Sep 14 14:18 .
- drwxrwxr-x  11 root     4127         512 Sep 14 14:18 ..
- drwxrwxr-x   2 root     4127         512 Sep 13 15:18 RCS
- lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     bin           11 Jun 29 14:34 README -> welcome.msg
- drwxr-xr-x   3 root     wheel        512 May 19  1998 bin
- drwxr-sr-x   3 root     1400         512 Jun  9  1997 dev
- drwxrwxr--   2 root     4127         512 Feb  8  1998 dup
- drwxr-xr-x   3 root     wheel        512 May 19  1998 etc
...
```

Else, you may go with the SSH using [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). Use whichever suits you better.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='none', 
    password='lol')
```

Ftplib code reference: [The ftplib module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm)

Paramiko code reference: [SSH PROGRAMMING WITH PARAMIKO | COMPLETELY DIFFERENT](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different)